# WP_Query displays all posts whatever I set up in arguments

Tags: wordpress

When I set up Wp_Query with those arguments:

```
$property = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type'  => 'rec_resource_dir_ltg',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'city',
        'value'   => 'Rostov',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
) ) );
```

It displays me all posts but not ones with the value I set up.

The code I use for displaying posts if $property get posts:

```
if( $property->have_posts() ) : 
?>
<div class="row">
<?php while( $property->have_posts() ) :
     $property->the_post(); //... after that create layout of posts
```

I've checked the key and value. There are posts with those values.

Does anybody know why the Wp_Query doesn't filter the posts?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. If you do a `count($property)` on the next line, does that show the right number of posts or is it also showing all of them? Can you show us the code where you use $property in case there is something there?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I've added the code I use to display posts if $property isn't empty. 

I don't know why but count($property) always shows "1" no matter how many posts dilsplay or should display.